# ULN2003 does not distribute power equally to all pins

Tags: current, dc-motor, uln2003

I'm facing a problem when I try control more than one DC motor with a [ULN2003](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uln2003.pdf) Darlington array.

Issue:

When I turn on one output, the motor turns in 4s. When I turn on two outputs, the first motor makes a turn in 4s, the other in 5s. When I turn on three outputs, the third motor does one turn in 10s.

Is there any solution to distribute power equally to all outputs?

I'm powering the control board with 24 V/2 A. Consumption is about 170 mA, so the power supply isn't a problem.

I'm attaching schematics and PCB layout.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are your base resistors? Also, please post oscillograms of input and output pins.

Comment: ULN2003 has integrated base bias, it's logic level compatible.

Comment: @Lorenzo, It's the lack of base resistors on Q1 to Q28 that winny is asking about. When the ULN open-collector output pulls low there is no current limit for Q1/2's base current.

Comment: oh these:D yep, the base on the PNP is overdriven. And it has put BJTs in parallel which is a big no-no in itself. I'd expect magic smoke in a short time, in that case. I was looking at the ULN issue only. A beefier PNP or even a channel P MOSFET would have been a better choice.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is enough to answer your question but here it is.

The boxed section is copied from ULN200x datasheet. And I've shown for only 17th output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTKQK5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When you apply a logic input to INx, the Qa-Qb Darlington pair inside the chip will pull the output O17 to ground, then the two paralleled output transistors' (Q5 & Q6) bases will see GND.

Basically, this will short the 24V supply with two paralleled diodes and cause the output voltage of the supply to drop. Normally you should have ended up with burnt transistors so I suggest you to check the transistors, just in case. And you'd better check the power supply as well because we don't know if it's capable of protecting itself.

As you activate more loads the 24V supply voltage will drop more. If the speed of your motors is related to the supply voltage then the speed may get slower as more loads are activated.

The solution is to place resistor (RX) between the chip's output (O17) and R3's bottom end:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxdEBB.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The ULN2003 is *not* a matched or precision array, they don't guarantee that the transistor or the bias resistor are anything near being equal. So the current will distribute in the way it prefers (i.e. thru the smallest impedance). Also if you are working with 3.3V drive the ULN often is a little starved for base current (it's really designed for 5V). Check your Vces, maybe that's the case.

Motors also have really big tolerances. So I wouldn't bet on that. 170mA shouldn't be an issue even if you daisy chain your ULNs (the one nearest to the 24V supply sees a slighly lower trace resistance so it would put out a little more juice).

If you really need to control the speed of your motor use some kind of retroaction control (typically a PWM drive and some kind of speed sensor)